# Order by CASE on an enum in jOOQ - no explicit type comparator

Tags: java, postgresql, kotlin, jooq

I have this PostgreSQL type definition and table

```
CREATE TYPE T_TIER_TYPE AS ENUM (
    'TOP_TIER',
    'MID_TIER',
    'LOW_TIER'
    )
;

CREATE TABLE properties (
    tier_code           T_TIER_TYPE NOT NULL,
    tier_id             VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    property_name       VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    property_value      VARCHAR(256) [] NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (tier_code, tier_id, property_name)
)
;
```

So that I can define many layers of properties for each one of my customers.   They must be composed in such way that the property definitions in LOW_TIER override those in MID_TIER, which override those of TOP_TIER.  I have tried to express that in JOOQ like this:

```
fun getProperties(tiers: Tiers): List<PROPERTIES_REC>? =
    dsl.selectFrom(properties)
        .where(properties.tier_code.eq(TOP_TIER).and(properties.tier_id.eq(tiers[TOP_TIER])))
        .or(properties.tier_code.eq(MID_TIER).and(properties.tier_id.eq(tiers[MID_TIER])))
        .or(properties.tier_code.eq(LOW_TIER).and(properties.tier_id.eq(tiers[LOW_TIER])))
        .orderBy(properties.tier_code.sortAsc(TOP_TIER, MID_TIER, LOW_TIER))
        .fetch()
```

The important part of the query is the `sortAsc` bit.  This way I can just `toMap` the results after this and apply effortlessly the hierarchy explained before.  I am getting this error when running the query:

> ERROR: operator does not exist: t_tier_type = character varying
> Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You
> might need to add explicit type casts.

I can dodge my problem by adding a cast to varchar as suggested and comparing to the name of the enum values of the type - however, does anybody know a more appropriate solution for this one?

Comment: Are those `TOP_TIER` references from generated code? If so, that should work out of the box. If it doesn't please can you file a bug? https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new/choose. If it's not generated code, it's a good opportunity to think about using the code generator, instead :)

Comment: No, I have forced a converter for reusing my own `Tier` type, that is actually older than this implementation - I will take a look at it!! Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I see. Well, jOOQ needs some `org.jooq.EnumType` information attached to your enum to know how to cast it to the appropriate type...

Comment: Notice - you can answer your own questions here on Stack Overflow. Perhaps your answer will be useful for someone who visits this question in the future, with a similar problem